# Azure Media Player - Having trouble turning off logo - watermark

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I found a good article "Turn off Azure Media Services logo in media player", but I'm still having trouble getting it to go away.

[image: Azure Media Player showing logo - watermark]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Azure Media Player</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!--*****START OF Azure Media Player Scripts*****-->
    <!--Note: DO NOT USE the "latest" folder in production. Replace "latest" with a version number like "1.0.0"-->
    <!--EX:<script src="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.0.0/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>-->
    <!--Azure Media Player versions can be queried from //amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/changelog.html-->
<link href="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>
<!--*****END OF Azure Media Player Scripts*****-->

</head>
<body>

<video id="azuremediaplayer" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered" controls autoplay width="800" height="475" poster="" data-setup='{"logo": { "enabled": false}, "techOrder": ["azureHtml5JS", "flashSS", "silverlightSS", "html5"], "nativeControlsForTouch": true' tabindex="0">
    <source src="http://sterisuniversity.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/fae4bb4a-0064-4b13-b602-aba3b378f233/Vedder.ism/Manifest" type="application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml" />
    <p class="amp-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video</p>
</video>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Link to that article?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the end } of the data-setup. You should also set nativeControlsForTouch to false as outlined in out [documentation](http://aka.ms/ampdocs) - this will still allow for touch, but will disable the native player skin from showing through.

```
<video id="azuremediaplayer" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered" controls autoplay width="800" height="475" poster="" data-setup='{"logo": { "enabled": false}, "techOrder": ["azureHtml5JS", "flashSS", "silverlightSS", "html5"], "nativeControlsForTouch": false}' tabindex="0">
    <source src="http://sterisuniversity.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/fae4bb4a-0064-4b13-b602-aba3b378f233/Vedder.ism/Manifest" type="application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml" />
    <p class="amp-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video</p>
</video>
```